# install knn package into R

Tags: r

i got this messagge while installing knn into R, Any help plz

Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 7229440 != reported length 8244069
2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'igraph/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: This question is not appropriate for this forum, and is more suited for stackexchange. But I think I do know the answer. There is no package called "knn". You can find the list of packages [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html).

Comment: You need to provide to command which triggered the error.

Comment: There is indeed no package `knn` on CRAN. However, `install.packages("knn")` leads to a different error message. The message looks more like it was produced while installing `igraph`.